# php callback function in class

Tags: php, class, hosting, php-5.2

for some reasons, our hosting company used PHP 5.2 and doesn't even have mysqli and PDO pre-installed.

I have no choice but to rewrite some part of my code to make it 5.2 compatible.

so, here is my question:

In PHP 5.2 Anonymous function is not supported, so i did the following test to make sure I'm changing the code correctly:

```
class foo{

    public function toString(){
        $arr = array("a", "b");
        $arr2 = array("c", "d");
        print_r(array_map('mapKeyValue', $arr, $arr2));
    }

    private function mapKeyValue($v, $k){
        return $k."='".$v."'";
    }
}

$foo = new foo();
echo $foo->toString();
```

but the above would give me :

```
Warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'mapKeyValue' not found or invalid function name in ....
PHP Warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'mapKeyValue' not found or invalid function name in ....
```

what is the correct way to do :

```
array_map('mapKeyValue', $arr, $arr2);
```

within a class?

PS: Is it a good enough reason to change hosting company because they use PHP 5.2?(i got a contract with about 7 month left)

Comment: "I have no choice but to rewrite some part of my code to make it 5.2 compatible." Or get a new host that isn't insecure by default.

Comment: Tell your host that you want PHP upgraded, sometimes they will actually do it.

Comment: they actually refused saying that : '5.2 supports other client better since it has "less strict standards" than 5.3'

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `$this` and an array as the callback:

```
array_map( array( $this, 'mapKeyValue'), $arr, $arr2);
```

And, just to be sure, this is [tested with PHP 5.2.17](http://viper-7.com/wHL6mA) and is confirmed working.

Answer (score 4):

Try using :

```
print_r(array_map(array($this, "mapKeyValue") , $arr, $arr2));
```

You need to call the function using $this.

Comment: `&$this` will not boost performance, and in later versions of PHP call-time pass-by-reference has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_map(array($this, 'mapKeyValue'), $arr, $arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your that callback method is **public**.

```
public function mapKeyValue($v, $k){
    return $k."='".$v."'";
}

print_r(array_map(array($this, "mapKeyValue") , $arr, $arr2));
```