# Drupal errors: valid callback & preg_replace

Tags: php, drupal, callback

I moved a Drupal site from GoDaddy to AWS. Everything seems to work except on the contact page displays the following errors:

```
warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'utf8_encode' not found or invalid function name in /var/www/html/includes/unicode.inc on line 304.
: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/html/includes/unicode.inc on line 311.
: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/html/includes/unicode.inc on line 311.
: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/html/includes/unicode.inc on line 311.
```

This is line 304:

```
      $table = array_map('utf8_encode', $table);
```

This is line 311:

```
    return preg_replace('/&(#x?)?([A-Za-z0-9]+);/e', '_decode_entities("$1", "$2", "$0", $newtable, $exclude)', $text);
}
```

I tried changing to preg_replace_callback and that caused another error.

I am running php 5.6 if that helps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179552/php-callback-function-in-class

Comment: anyone else? This is over my head